# Add order comments to invoice/shipment pdf

Tags: orders, pdf, magento2.2.4, invoice-pdf

Files controling invoice/shipment order pdf content are the following:

- `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`
- `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`

Is it possible to add order comments in these pdf prints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can do.

At Invoice.php, you can get Order object using `$this->Order();`

then using `$this->Order()->getStatusHistoryCollection()` using you can get comment history collection.